# Handling HTTP requests

Tags: php, http

This class handles HTTP requests. It's a singleton class that parses URI to get the controller, method and parameters and then executes the controller's method.

Maybe `parseUri` should be in another class and maybe there is too much responsibility for this class.

I know that it can be improved. The execute method could be better because there are some repeated code.

```
<?php
class Request
{
    private static $_instance;
    private $_host;
    private $_request_uri;
    private $_script_name;
    private $_controller;
    private $_method;
    private $_parameters;
    private $_headers;

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->_host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $this->_request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $this->_script_name = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        $this->_headers = array();

        $this->_parseUri();
    }

    private function _parseUri()
    {
        /* In 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar/' get the '/foo/bar/' part */
        $part = str_replace(
            dirname($this->_script_name),
            '',
            $this->_request_uri
        );

        /* break it into chunks and clean up empty positions */
        $chunks = explode('/', $part);
        $chunks = array_filter($chunks);

        if (count($chunks))
        {
            if ($this->_controller = array_shift($chunks))
            {
                $this->_controller = ucfirst($this->_controller) . '_Controller';
            }

            if ($this->_method = array_shift($chunks))
            {
                $this->_method = ucfirst($this->_method) . 'Action';
            }
            $this->_parameters = $chunks ? $chunks : null;
        }
    }

    private function _send_headers()
    {
        foreach($this->_headers as $header)
        {
            header($header);
        }
    }

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (!self::$_instance)
        {
            self::$_instance = new Request();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /* There is a controller ... */
        if (!empty($this->_controller))
        {
            if (!class_exists($this->_controller, true))
            {
                array_push($this->_headers, 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
                $this->_send_headers();
                return;
            }

            $controller = new $this->_controller();
            /* ... and a method */
            if ($this->_method)
            {
                if (!method_exists($controller, $this->_method))
                {
                    array_push($this->_headers, 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
                    $this->_send_headers();
                    return;
                }

                $method = new ReflectionMethod(
                    $controller, $this->_method
                );

                /* Do we have parameters? Let's call the right method */
                $this->_parameters
                    ? $method->invokeArgs($controller, $this->_parameters)
                    : $method->invoke($controller);

                array_push($this->_headers, 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
                $this->_send_headers();
            }
            /* we don't have a method here, let's call the 'index_action' method */
            else
            {
                $method = new ReflectionMethod($controller, 'indexAction');
                $method->invoke($controller);

                array_push($this->_headers, 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
                $this->_send_headers();
            }
        }
        /* We don't have a Controller, let's call the default one. */
        else
        {
            if (!class_exists('Default_Controller', true))
            {
                throw new RequestException("'Default_Controller' class not found.");
            }

            $controller = new Default_Controller();

            if (!method_exists($controller, 'indexAction'))
            {
                throw new RequestException(
                    "'indexAction' method not found in 'Default_Controller' class."
                );
            }

            $method = new ReflectionMethod($controller, 'indexAction');
            $method->invoke($controller);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think there is too much responsibility for this class. I also think that it's name is a misnomer. A more appropriate name would be a `FrontController` or `RequestHandler` rather than `Request`. When I see an object named `Request` I expect something that wraps around a HTTP request, providing easy access to the underlying request data and state. I.e. I expect something that *is* a request rather than something that *processes* requests.

If you want to reduce/divide the responsibilities of this class, have a look at how other PHP frameworks have divided these, for example, Symfony2. Symfony2 has a `FrontController` object (they call it a `Kernel`) that has two parts: a `Router` and a `Resolver`. You put `Request` objects into the `Kernel` and you get `Response` objects back.

Internally, the `Kernel` passes the `Request` to the `Router`. The `Router` figures out which `Controller` and `Action` are being requested. This information is then passed to the `Resolver` which tries to load the actual PHP class that holds the `Controller` and `Action`. The `Kernel` then executes the `Controller/Action` which returns a `Response` object, which is (usually) displayed by the `Kernel`.

Answer (score 3):

Only something litle, don't write the closing `?>` , because if there is a whitespace after and you try to modifiy the header anywhere else, it won't work and you will have very very long to find the whitespace.

Comment: I disagree. I would argue that closing PHP mode is good practice.

Comment: "I disagree. I would argue that closing PHP mode is good practice" - You won't say that when you've wasted a day or more of time trying to find some errant whitespace.

Comment: `throw new NotACodeReviewException()`